# Assertion failed: you modified <computed var> twice

Tags: ember.js

I have two related models, an `Order` which contains several `Payment`s.

`Order` also has a `total` property. Each `Payment` is a `percentage` of the total. Therefore, when `total` changes, each `payment` observes it and calculates its partial `total`.

My problem arises from the fact that `Order` has also an `Ember.computed.sum` of those totals, in case the percentages are not yet 100%.

Ember.js issues an `"Assertion Failed: You modified computedTotal twice on <iec-jbe@component:order-form::ember906> in a single render. This was unreliable and slow in Ember 1.x and is no longer supported. See https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13948 for more details."`.

I understand why this happens, but I can't see a better way to do what I need to do. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Please show your computed prop. Anyway I think there is a problem which could be solved with http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_once

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me. It may not be the most elegant way, but it saved me a lot of refactoring

Comment: Sorry, I added it now.

Comment: Great, thanks. Also, if you want to attract someone's attention, please use their name (like `@halfer`, tab completion is available). I don't have to here though since this is your post, and you get all notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using `Ember.run.once` as suggested by Ebrahim Pasbani in a comment, and further developped here: [Observers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/observers/).

This may not be the best solution, but due to the very advanced state of our project, refactoring so to use computed properties instead of one observer would have meant so many changes it wasn't worth it. I say this to make clear this is *not the best solution* for most cases, it just the best solution in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should refactor, that you don't use observers. Just use a computed property for `total`, and do your logic in the setter.

Comment: I actually started refactoring as you said before realising it is not so easy. The payments are encapsulated in their own `Component`, and these cannot expose methods publicly. Further refactoring to make the payments a part of the order instead of individual compoments would be absolutely enormous, and that's something I would only consider if I am completely sure it's going to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but you definitely *should not* use observers for business logic! And to make sure it will work, just build a simple proof of concept. Shouldn't be that hard to build a twiddle with what you described.